# Reading Partial Messages in NetworkStream Async Read Callback

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, stream

We have a C# application that is communicating with a device over TCP/IP using a relatively simple protocol consisting of a series of messages, which have a fixed-size header and a variable length payload. The header contains the length of the payload.

Recently we converted the programming model from synchronous to asynchronous, and now have an interesting problem: how to handle partially received messages.

**Synchronous Code**

```
public void ReceiveMessage(NetworkStream stream)
{
    // Read the header from the stream
    MessageHeader header = stream.ReadHeader();

    int payloadBytesRead = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[header.PayloadSize];

    // Keep reading from the stream until the payload
    // is fully extracted
    while (payloadBytesRead < header.PayloadSize)
    {
        payloadBytesRead += stream.Read(buffer, payloadBytesRead, header.PayloadSize - payloadBytesRead);
    }

    MessagePayload = new MessagePayload(buffer);

    // Do something with the message here
    // ...

}
```

where `ReadHeader` is an extension method on `NetworkStream` to extract the fixed-size header out of the stream.

**Problem with Async Version**

In the async version, where we use `BeginRead` and `EndRead`, there is a chance that the read callback may be invoked with a partially received message in the buffer. Since the callback is invoked *after* the data has been pulled from the stream, leaving the partial message in the stream for the next callback is not possible. However, we have to keep this partial data until the next callback so that it can be processed later.

It seems the only solution is to copy the partial data bytes to a different buffer, or to shift them to the bottom of the receive buffer before the next `BeginRead` is invoked. Is this correct, or is there a more common technique for handling this scenario?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Varies. In general we code around 3.5, but we also have some targets which have to support 2.0.